# How to parse attributes which contains dots with --format for docker events output?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I am trying to parse `docker events` output and format it using the `--format` argument.
It works for basic attributes, however I can't manage to use attributes containing dots, like those from Docker Swarm.

Here is an example:

```bash
$ docker events --since=5m --until=1s --filter type=container --format '{{ json . }}'
```

```json
{
  "status": "oom",
  "id": "23916078dbf062b02edf36ae1de3cdd6d439d11cad29acc72daffcc1ac8981b9",
  "from": "(redacted)",
  "Type": "container",
  "Action": "oom",
  "Actor": {
    "ID": "23916078dbf062b02edf36ae1de3cdd6d439d11cad29acc72daffcc1ac8981b9",
    "Attributes": {
      "com.docker.stack.namespace": "beta-client",
      "com.docker.swarm.node.id": "woxyp548c8yat5nizwzmar6ia",
      "com.docker.swarm.service.id": "5j72edfv4sda554gqu0paaxu2",
      "com.docker.swarm.service.name": "beta-client_task",
      "com.docker.swarm.task": "",
      "com.docker.swarm.task.id": "ib57fy6em8hz1cfbrua518r2i",
      "com.docker.swarm.task.name": "beta-client_task.1.ib57fy6em8hz1cfbrua518r2i",
      "image": "(redacted)",
      "name": "beta-client_task.1.ib57fy6em8hz1cfbrua518r2i"
    }
  },
  "scope": "local",
  "time": 1559032467,
  "timeNano": 1559032467083181300
}
```

I would like to fetch the `com.docker.stack.namespace` attribute, in `Actor.Attributes` (without using an external tool like `jq`).

But the dots in the attribute name prevents me from accessing this attribute, and quoting it doesn't seem to work:

```bash
$ docker events --since=5m --until=1s --filter type=container --format '{{ .Actor.Attributes."com.docker.stack.namespace" }}'
```

```bash
Error parsing format: template: :1: bad character U+0022 '"'
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use `.` if parameter name also have `.` in it. Try `index`, something like follows:

```
--format '{{ index .Actor.Attributes "com.docker.stack.namespace" }}'
```